# How do I visualize current site traffic from multiple Google Analytics accounts on a single dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like some advice how to visualize current web traffic from 13 different e-shops (13 separate GA accounts) in real time. We are currently using Tableau for visualization, where we are dragging data through our own connector, but to yesterday's date. We are looking for a solution to display current traffic for customer care service.

Is the direct connection of GA to Tableau secure and would it be possible to connect and visualize 13 separate GA accounts on one dashboard or is it necessary to merge these accounts?

Comment: This is a solid guide: https://vizpainter.com/multiple-google-analytics-accounts-in-one-tableau-data-source/